# VB.NET How to: Grab an Excel chart from an worksheet and insert it into a form

Tags: excel, vb.net

Ok, VB.NET novice here... I've been tasked with creating a dashboard and on this dashboard(Windows application), the powers that be want to see graphs that already exist in an Excel worksheet.

I've just learned that I can grab the values of cells from a worksheet, which is super cool, but since I don't want to reinvent the wheel each time the powers ask for a new chart to be displayed on this dashboard, I want to know if I can just grab a specific chart from the worksheet rather than just the data which I will then manipulate into a VB.NET chart.  My Google-fu is failing me on this specific answer, so I'm turning to the experts for some help here.

I've got 8 charts needed to be displayed and I can imagine more will be added over time, so looking to save myself some work here.

Answer (score 0):

Woot!

xlWorkSheet.ChartObjects(1).chart.Export(FileName:="C:\temp\excel_chart_export.bmp", FilterName:="BMP")

Now just set that to a picturebox and you're good to go.